# How do I browse a different git branch without checking it out

Tags: git, merge, branch, branching-and-merging, git-merge

I've just merged two branches in git. Now I'm examining my (broken) code in Eclipse (on Windows). I'd like to be able to browse the HEAD of the source branch without checking it out. I know I can use [git-show](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html) to see a single file in another branch, but ideally I'd like to be able to (locally) see the directory tree of the source branch, and jump from file to file easily. I already have [git-extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) installed in case there's a way to use that that I've missed.

If there isn't a way to do this locally I assume I'll have to browse the (remote) repository, but I'd rather do it locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using **Git-Gui**, you can browse files in different branches without checking them out. In Git-Gui, go to **Repository** menu, then click on **Browse Branch Files**, choose any branch, click on **Browse** button. It opens a new window, where you can browse thorough directory tree of the selected branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use git-daemon and the webinterface?!

Answer (score 0):

You already have Git Extensions, and that provides a way to browse the file tree.  Click on any commit, and there are tabs at the bottom that show the Commit, File Tree and Diff.  Just click on "File Tree" to browse the contents of files as they would appear at the time of that commit.